# How to define constructor of fully-specialized class within another class template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

I have a class template that contains another class template, and the inner template has an explicit specialization:

```
template <typename Outer>
struct ContainingClass {
  template <typename T>
  struct Rule {
    Rule(T value);

    // ... other members ...
  };

  template <>
  struct Rule<void> {
    Rule();

    // ... different members than the non-void Rule<T> ...
  };
};
```

I've defined the constructors for both the generic and specialized `Rule`:

```
template <typename Outer>
template <typename T>
ContainingClass<Outer>::Rule<T>::Rule(T value) { }

template <typename Outer>
ContainingClass<Outer>::Rule<void>::Rule() { }
```

But Clang doesn't like the specialized class's constructor:

```
error: nested name specifier 'ContainingClass<Outer>::Rule<void>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
ContainingClass<Outer>::Rule<void>::Rule() { }
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

I'm puzzled by this, because it "refers into" `ContainingClass<Outer>`, which *is* a class (an instance of the `ContainingClass` class template).  I suspect I need to change something in the syntax for this, but it's not clear what.  How can I define this constructor?

(It works if I remove `ContainingClass` and put `Rule` at namespace scope, but I need to have other things in `Rule` that depend on the `Outer` type.  I could give `Rule` its own `Outer` template parameter, but that'll make things more awkward for the code that uses this class, so I'd like to avoid it if possible.  And I know I can define the constructor inline within the `Rule` class body, but I'd like to understand why the separate definition isn't working.)

In case it matters, I'm using both Clang 8.0 in Ubuntu 19.04, and Apple's "clang-1001.0.46.4" on a Mac.  (I've also tried Ubuntu's GCC 8.3, but that fails in a different place due to [GCC bug #85282](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282) — "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope" on the definition of `struct Rule<void>` itself.)

**Edited to clarify:**  My error isn't about having the `template <> struct Rule<void>` specialization within `ContainingClass`.  That's the subject of a C++14 limitation ([defect CWG 727](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#727)), which is worked around by adding a dummy template parameter so the template is only partially- instead of fully-specialized.  I believe that limitation has been lifted in C++17, and the specialization of the `Rule` class itself works fine in Clang (though GCC has the bug).  So I think the dummy parameter workaround is not the right solution here — but please tell me if I'm mistaken and there are still limitations on this in C++17.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested class template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099306/nested-class-template-specialization)

Comment: @krisz, that limitation exists in C++14, but has been lifted in C++17, and that's not the error that I'm getting.  (Except in GCC, due to the bug I mentioned.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not declare at namespace scope a member of a specialization of template member of a template.

To avoid this limitation, you can use a work around that used to be necessary for c++14 and earlier which consists in using a partial specialization instead of a full specialization:

```
template <typename Outer>
struct ContainingClass {
  template <typename T,class=void>
  struct Rule {
    Rule(T value);

    // ... other members ...
  };

  template <class U>
  struct Rule<void,U> {
    Rule();

    // ... different members than the non-void Rule<T> ...
  };
};

template <typename Outer>
template <typename T, typename U>
ContainingClass<Outer>::Rule<T,U>::Rule(T value) { }

template <typename Outer>
template <typename U>
ContainingClass<Outer>::Rule<void,U>::Rule() { }
```

In C++17 it is still impossible to declare (a member of) a specialization member of a class template at namespace scope, see [[temp.expl.spec]/17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#16). The same paragraph exists [in the C++14 standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.expl.spec#16).

What changed with C++17 is that we can declare a specialization of the member inside the enclosing class template definition:

- [C++14/[templ.expl.spec]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.expl.spec#2)

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template.[...]

- [C++17/[templ.expl.spec]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#2)

> An explicit specialization may be declared in any scope in which the corresponding primary template may be defined.[...]

Comment: Confusingly similar to the C++14 limitation (and GCC bug) that an explicit specialization has to be at namespace scope, not class scope.  So it's just not allowed at all, even in 17?

Comment: Thanks for the references you added — I see the distinction now.